# pytest error: ImportError: cannot import name 'Expression' from '_pytest.mark'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I'm getting this error:

```
conftest.py:95: in <module>
    from framework.scheduler import PytestScheduler
framework/scheduler.py:33: in <module>
    from _pytest.mark import Expression, MarkMatcher
E   ImportError: cannot import name 'Expression' from '_pytest.mark' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/_pytest/mark/__init__.py)
```

could it possibly be my version of pytest? How do I know which version should I use?

The file `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/_pytest/mark/__init__.py` exists so it's installed.

Comment: What code is throwing this error? it might be a version issue, what version are you using? try to update it.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo pip install --upgrade attrs==21.2.0
sudo pip install --upgrade pytest==6.2.4
```

fixed for me